# How to add feature extracted layer to a sequential model in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```py
resnet_50 = "https://www.kaggle.com/models/tensorflow/resnet-50/frameworks/TensorFlow2/variations/classification/versions/1"
feature_extractor_model = resnet_50
import tensorflow_hub as hub
feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(
    feature_extractor_model,
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
    trainable=False)
num_classes = len(class_names)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(feature_extractor_layer)
model.summary()
```

I am trying to add the `feature_extractor_layer` to the Sequential, but getting the following error:

> ValueError: Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be added to a Sequential model. Received: <tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x7b6c00794850> (of type <class 'tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer'>)

How to resolve this?